# How to make CoordinateTransformer nullable in PROJ library

Tags: c++, proj

I'm using C++ PROJ library to convert points between different coordinate reference systems.
I have a simple class that wraps all the PROJ boilerplate and exposes a single method to transform coordinates.

I'm trying to reuse `CoordinateTransformer` between conversions but I can't figure out a way to store it inside a class instance.

I've tried adding two fields

```
CoordinateTransformerNNPtr transformerHorizontal;
CoordinateTransformerNNPtr transformerVertical;
```

and assigning transformers in the constructor on my class (see code below), but it doesn't work presumably because `CoordinateTransformerNNPtr` is a `CoordinateTransformerPtr` wrapped into `util::nn` which doesn't allow having a nullable pointer inside it. The problem is that when instanciating my class I don't have anything to store in these fields, so they have to be nullable.

The error with my current code is `Constructor for 'LidarCoordinateDecoder' must explicitly initialize the member 'transformerHorizontal' which does not have a default constructor`.

The reason why I'm trying to reuse `CoordinateTransformer` is to improve performance.

My code:

```
class LidarCoordinateDecoder {
private:
    CoordinateOperationPtr transformationHorizontal;
    CoordinateOperationPtr transformationVertical;
    PJ_CONTEXT *context;
    CoordinateTransformerNNPtr transformerHorizontal;
    CoordinateTransformerNNPtr transformerVertical;

public:
    LidarCoordinateDecoder(int epsgHorizontal, int epsgVertical) {
        auto dbContext = DatabaseContext::create();
        auto authFactory = AuthorityFactory::create(dbContext, std::string());
        auto authFactoryEPSG = AuthorityFactory::create(dbContext, "EPSG");

        auto sourceHorizontalCRS = authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem(std::to_string(epsgHorizontal));
        auto sourceVerticalCRS = authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem(std::to_string(epsgVertical));

        auto targetHorizontalCRS = authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem("4326");
        auto targetVerticalCRS = authFactoryEPSG->createCoordinateReferenceSystem("5773");

        transformationHorizontal = CoordinateOperationFactory::create()->createOperation(sourceHorizontalCRS, targetHorizontalCRS);
        transformationVertical = CoordinateOperationFactory::create()->createOperation(sourceVerticalCRS, targetVerticalCRS);

        transformerHorizontal = transformationHorizontal->coordinateTransformer(context);
        transformerVertical = transformationVertical->coordinateTransformer(context);

        context = proj_context_create();
    }

    std::tuple<double, double, double> convert(double x, double y, double elevation) {
        PJ_COORD c = {{x, y, 0, 0}};
        c = transformerHorizontal->transform(c);

        double lat = c.v[0];
        double lon = c.v[1];

        c = {{c.v[0], c.v[1], elevation, 0}};
        c = transformerVertical->transform(c);

        return std::make_tuple(lat, lon, c.v[2]);
    }

    ~LidarCoordinateDecoder() = default;
};
```

Comment: In C++? But there are piles. Pointers are nullable, smart pointers are nullable, std::optional is nullable. Also you might want to think about that constructor, creating several temporary factories feels like lot of responsibilities.